# WCF endpoints on production server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have made a simple WCF service, and it´s working like a charm in my developer environment. But now I'm moving it to my test server (AZURE) and i can´t get the endpoint address correct. The IIS is up and running, and the service is working locally on the test server.

When I try to test the service in WCF Test client, I receive an error when I try to invoke that the endpoint is incorrect:

> There was no endpoint listening at mypathattestserver/Service1.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.

This is my web.config:

```
  <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Test.Service1Behavior" name="Test.tfn">

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Test.IService1">  

      <identity>
        <dns value="http://mypathattestserver.cloudapp.net/service1.svc"/>
      </identity>       
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Test.Service1Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot get the service up and running? What's going wrong? Does an exception occur?

Comment: Yes im sorry! Forgont to mention it...

 When i try to test the service in WCF Test client i receive an error when i try to invoke that the endpoint is incorrect.


There was no endpoint listening at http://mypathattestserver/Service1.svc that could accept the message.
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: So it seems that i have some kind of error with the endpoint in web.config...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following steps:

- Check the service with **another client**. [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a very good web service client. If the service responds to SoapUI then the problem is on your client
- If the server is fine and the problem is at your client, **remove the reference** looking at the specific server and **add it again**.
- Finally, **check your firewalls**. If the system plays fine by having the client and the server on the same machine, the firewalls could be a problem when the server is located on another machine.

Hope I helped!

Comment: The error must be with the endpoint section in web.config when i load the service on the test enviroment the path to the service is: 
svcutil.exe http://mypathattestserver/Service1.svc?wsdl when it should be something like http://mypathattestserver.server.net/Service1.svc?wsdl